# How do I ground a new outlet that only has the black/white wires?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, grounding

I am adding a new outlet but want to make sure it is correctly grounded.

I have outlet A that I am going to be creating a new outlet B. I tested A and it says it is grounded and want to ground outlet B the same way. How do I see how outlet A is grounded and do the same as B if there is no grounding wire?

I am assuming that it is grounded through the metal outlet box.  [image][image]

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph. How will the old outlet be part of the circuit?

Comment: I disagree that it’s a dup of that question, but it’s very likely a dup of something else.  The way I read this OP’s question he that he has existing outlet A, which *tests* that it has a good ground—the wiring method is unclear but it must likely be conduit or metal clad something to provide ground.  He wants to extend the circuit from outlet A and add a new outlet B, using /2 with ground.  We also don’t know if current outlet A has a bootleg ground, which is another possibility.

Comment: Should the question be more of how do I know how outlet A is grounded so I can ground the new outlet b the same way?

Comment: @jokim yes.  At a very minimum if my assessment is correct you could re-write the question using A and B to make it easier to understand.  I can see how a quick read now causes confusion.

Comment: Can you look in the back of the box to see what the wiring method is? Wires going into multi-conductor cable that is clamped? Or disappearing into a pipe?

Comment: @harper I would have to cut the wall to see what is going on in the back of the box.

Comment: No, you just unscrew the receptacle cover and receptacle, pull the receptacle out a bit and look behind it in the back of the box. . Breaker switched off, of course.  In fact could you post pix of that?

Comment: If it is a metal box , I have run into some old homes that were grounded through the box but the ground connection was outside the box FWIW.

Comment: @harper I added a pic. Cannot get the box off. I think it’s nails to the back

Comment: Perfect.   No need to take apart the building.  In fact if you need more than a screwdriver to access any junction point,  that's a code violation!

Comment: @harper it was actually was in place by metal clips. I was able to get the box off. Is it grounded by the metal wire case?

Answer (score 2):

You can Install a GFCI outlet that has an 'equivalent' protection to be used in outlets where PE is not present.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have metal shielded cable ("bx cable") to the box.

In some jurisdictions, the metal jacket of the conduit is or used to be an acceptable ground.

Consult an electrician to verify.

Answer (score 1):

### The box is grounded, just not *well*

While the armor of old type BX cables does not meet modern grounding standards, it *is* grounded, so it's best that you use it instead of ignoring it.  A *self-grounding* receptacle (it will have little clips on the yoke that bear against the mounting screws) should be used here, and the ground wires in any cables you are running from there should be made up to a ground screw on the box.

Comment: What does downstream cables mean?

Comment: @jokim -- any new cables that you're running from that box.

Comment: The new outlet is going to be inside a cabnet, does the metal box need to be inside the wall or ok to just screw it inside the cabnet?

Comment: @jokim -- that should be a new question :)